# Amazon S3 and .htaccess, how to rewrite this url?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, amazon-s3

I setup a Wordpress installation in my main directory. Than I built inside Amazon S3 an HTML landing page that I wish to use as homepage. 
So on my .htaccess I use this line for redirect the homepage to my S3 bucket:

`RedirectMatch ^/$ http://mywebsite.org.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/`

and it works, but since I'm not familiar with Regex I'm not sure how to change this url into a simple `http://mywebsite.org`

How could I change my url rule within my .htaccess in this particular situation considering that `http://mywebsite.org` is my Wordpress homepage?

Comment: Maybe you do not need any regex here? `RedirectMatch ^/$ http://mywebsite.org/`?

Comment: @stribizhev as I wrote `http://mywebsite.org/` is my Wordpress page